# Include model, unless attribute is empty - node seqelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm calling information about User and want to include UserMeetingsReviews UNLESS an attribute contains an empty string:  `complement === ''`

If I use `include: [ where: { complement: '' } ]`, it includes all the records where complement is an empty string, no problems. To get only records without an empty string I've tried:

```
include: [ where: { 'complement': {[Op.ne]: '""'} }, ]

include: [ where: { 'complement != "" '}, ]

include: [ where: [ '`GroupMeetingsReviews`.`complement` != ""' ],]
```

All both throw an error.

This doesn't throw an error, but does include records where an empty string:

```
where: {[Op.not]: [ { complement: '""' }, ] },
```

In Rails it would be the equivalent of `where.not(complement: '')` - how can I include records with a negative where query in nodejs?

Here's full my file:

```
'use strict'
let users = {};
const { BlockedUsers, LanguagesUsers, ProSettings, Users, UserReviews, GroupMeetingsReviews, GroupMeetings, Languages } = require('../models');
let models = require("../models/index");

let Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let Op = Sequelize.Op;
let sequelizeDB = require('../modules/Sequelize');


users.getProfileByUserId = (req, res) => {
    models.Users.findOne({
      where: {id: req.params.userid},
      include: [
        {
          model: models.UserReviews,
          as: 'complements',
        },
        {
          model: models.GroupMeetingsReviews,
          where: {
            'complement': {[Op.ne]: ''}
          },
          as: 'groupComplements',
          include: [
            {
              model: models.Users,
              as: 'reviewee',
              attributes: ['id', 'avatar_file_name', 'first_name']
            },
            {
              model: models.Users,
              as: 'reviewer',
              attributes: ['id', 'avatar_file_name', 'first_name']
            },
            {
              model: models.GroupMeetings,
              as: 'group_meeting',
            },
          ]
        },
      ],
    }).then(user => {
        models.sequelize
          .query(
            "SELECT languages_users.level, languages_users.language_id, languages.native, languages.locale, languages.flag, languages.language FROM languages_users JOIN languages ON languages_users.language_id = languages.id WHERE languages_users.user_id = ? ORDER BY level DESC",
            {
              replacements: [req.params.userid],
              type: models.PushToken.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
            }
        )
        .then(languages => {
            user["encrypted_password"] = null;
            res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: { user, languages } });
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({ status: 500, err: error });
    });
};
```

With the below suggestion

```
model: models.GroupMeetingsReviews,
as: 'groupComplements',
where: {
  complement: {
    [Op.ne]: '',
  },
},
```

these are the server logs:

> 2018-09-27T15:04:57.197162+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing (default): SELECT "Users"."id", "Users"."email", "Users"."encrypted_password", "Users"."first_name", "Users"."last_name", "Users"."bio", "Users"."location", "Users"."avatar_file_name", "Users"."nationality", "Users"."status", "Users"."lat", "Users"."lng", "complements"."id" AS "complements.id", "complements"."reviewer" AS "complements.reviewer", "complements"."reviewee" AS "complements.reviewee", "complements"."meeting_id" AS "complements.meeting_id", "complements"."notes" AS "complements.notes", "complements"."created_at" AS "complements.created_at", "complements"."updated_at" AS "complements.updated_at", "groupComplements"."id" AS "groupComplements.id", "groupComplements"."reviewer_id" AS "groupComplements.reviewer_id", "groupComplements"."reviewee_id" AS "groupComplements.reviewee_id", "groupComplements"."group_meeting_id" AS "groupComplements.group_meeting_id", "groupComplements"."complement" AS "groupComplements.complement", "groupComplements"."reviewed" AS "groupComplements.reviewed", "groupComplements"."created_at" AS "groupComplements.created_at", "groupComplements"."updated_at" AS "groupComplements.updated_at", "groupComplements->reviewee"."id" AS "groupComplements.reviewee.id", "groupComplements->reviewee"."avatar_file_name" AS "groupComplements.reviewee.avatar_file_name", "groupComplements->reviewee"."first_name" AS "groupComplements.reviewee.first_name", "groupComplements->reviewer"."id" AS "groupComplements.reviewer.id", "groupComplements->reviewer"."avatar_file_name" AS "groupComplements.reviewer.avatar_file_name", "groupComplements->reviewer"."first_name" AS "groupComplements.reviewer.first_name", "groupComplements->group_meeting"."id" AS "groupComplements.group_meeting.id", "groupComplements->group_meeting"."lang_one_id" AS "groupComplements.group_meeting.lang_one_id", "groupComplements->group_meeting"."lang_two_id" AS "groupComplements.group_meeting.lang_two_id", "groupComplements->group_meeting"."location_name" AS "groupComplements.group_meeting.location_name", "groupComplements->group_meeting"."created_at" AS "groupComplements.group_meeting.created_at", "groupComplements->group_meeting"."updated_at" AS "groupComplements.group_meeting.updated_at" FROM "public"."users" AS "Users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."user_reviews" AS "complements" ON "Users"."id" = "complements"."reviewee" INNER JOIN "public"."group_meetings_reviews" AS "groupComplements" ON "Users"."id" = "groupComplements"."reviewee_id" AND "groupComplements"."complement" != '' LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "groupComplements->reviewee" ON "groupComplements"."reviewee_id" = "groupComplements->reviewee"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "groupComplements->reviewer" ON "groupComplements"."reviewer_id" = "groupComplements->reviewer"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."group_meetings" AS "groupComplements->group_meeting" ON "groupComplements"."group_meeting_id" = "groupComplements->group_meeting"."id" WHERE "Users"."id" = '32';
>
> 2018-09-27T15:04:57.224689+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot set property 'encrypted_password' of null
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224692+00:00 app[web.1]: at models.sequelize.query.then.languages (/app/controllers/Users.js:104:40)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224694+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.084036+00:00 app[web.1]: decoded token, { id: 32, created: 1537994368165, iat: 1537994368 }
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224698+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224702+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.217311+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing (default): SELECT languages_users.level, languages_users.language_id, languages.native, languages.locale, languages.flag, languages.language FROM languages_users JOIN languages ON languages_users.language_id = languages.id WHERE languages_users.user_id = '32' ORDER BY level DESC
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224705+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224707+00:00 app[web.1]: at _drainQueueStep (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224709+00:00 app[web.1]: at _drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224703+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224718+00:00 app[web.1]: at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224710+00:00 app[web.1]: at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224714+00:00 app[web.1]: at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224712+00:00 app[web.1]: at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>   2018-09-27T15:04:57.224716+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)

Comment: perhaps it's `null` and not `''`

Comment: @doublesharp My question is, what's the proper format to include an association, where an attribute is not equal to something. It doesn't matter what the attribute or value is.

Comment: Your first example - `where: { col: { [Op.ne]: value } }`

Comment: @doublesharp I tried `where: { 'complement': {[Op.ne]: '""'} },` but it includes records with `"complement": "",`

Answer (score 0):

To get results where `complement` is not `''` or `NULL` use the following syntax:

```
model: models.GroupMeetingsReviews,
as: 'groupComplements',
where: {
  complement: {
    [Op.ne]: '',
    [Op.ne]: null,
  },
},
required: true,
```

You can also add `logging: true` to your query to see the generated SQL via `console.log()` for additional debugging.

Comment: To clarify - the field will never be null. It's default is an empty string. As well - the above still returns records where `complement: ""`

Comment: Or is there a way to get the length of the string, and to say something like `only return records where complements.length > 1`?

Comment: it's not processing the where at all. have you included all the fiends in your model?

Comment: Yes, I have this in my GroupMeetingsReviews model: `complement: DataTypes.STRING,`